# Knex.js SQL Server running concurrently giving intermittent Error running query: Error: Unable to acquire a connection

Tags: javascript, sql-server, concurrency, knex.js, playwright

I'm using Knex.js in a nodejs env. The project I'm building is a test automation project rather than an application. Some of my test scenarios require an SQL Server database connection to retrieve link data. I have tested locally many times and I don't see that error happen, but when I run my tests concurrently on the ADO pipeline, I can see that error happen all the time but not on all the test scenarios.
Error showing as:

> Error running query: Error: Unable to acquire a connection
> at Client_MSSQL.acquireConnection (/appl/ado/agent/1/s/********/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:311:13)
> at Runner.ensureConnection (/appl/ado/agent/1/s/********/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:305:46)
> at Runner.run (/appl/ado/agent/1/s/********/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:30:30)
> at Builder.Target.then (/appl/ado/agent/1/s/********/node_modules/knex/lib/builder-interface-augmenter.js:24:43)

My knex configure is like:

```
const knex = require('knex');

const createDBInstance = (config) => {
  return knex({
    client: 'mssql',
    connection: {
      user: config.user,
      password: config.password,
      server: config.server,
      database: config.database,
      options: {
        encrypt: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
      },
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10
    }
  });
};

module.exports = createDBInstance;
```

and query method like:

```
const utilityManagerInstance = createDBInstance(utilityManagerDBConfig);

async function getLatest*******ByLinkType(linkType) {
  let result = null;
  try {
    result = await utilityManagerInstance
      .select('*')
      .from('***table')
      .whereRaw(`Payload.exist('//*[text()="${linkType}"]') = 1`)
      .orderBy(1, 'desc')
      .limit(1);
    return result[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error running query:', error);
  } finally {
    await utilityManagerInstance.destroy();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any input is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't ```.whereRaw(`Payload.exist('//*[text()="${linkType}"]') = 1`)``` open to an injection attack?